# ¿Programa que muestre una serie de x hasta y con incrementos de 1 omitiendo los números que sean múltiplos de z?

Tags: java

**Programa que muestre una serie de X hasta Y con incrementos de 1 omitiendo los números que sean múltiplos de Z. Solicite al usuario que el indique los valores de X,Y y Z. Valide que Y sea mayor a X**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class t10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de X");
        int x = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de Y");
        int y = leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de Z");
        int z = leer.nextInt();

        if (y > x && x % z == 0) {
            for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("X es mayor a Y");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores te marca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de X");
    int x = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de Y");
    int y = leer.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor de Z");
    int z = leer.nextInt();

       if (y > x) {
            for (int i = x; i <= y; i++) {
               //Aqui es donde deberias comparar si el numero actual del indice no es multiplo de z
                if(i % z != 0){
                    System.out.println("i = " + i);
                }
            }
    
        }else{
            System.out.println("X es mayor a Y");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Por favor leer [answer]. Toma en cuenta eso a futuro.